# Can't set size of canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a `<canvas>` element that is 500 by 1000 pixels, but my browser will only render an element of 300 by 150 pixels.

Here is my code:

```
var c=document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle='black';  
ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,1000);
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/R8cxH/

I don't understand this, because the outer `body` element is wider than 300 pixels.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/R8cxH/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the width and height of your newly created canvas

```
c.width = 500;
c.height = 1000;
```

Comment: @Pavlo you must set size *before* you use the element: http://jsfiddle.net/R8cxH/4/

Comment: @Pavlo the canvas is there it's just white, so you can't see it

Comment: @Pavlo (link above seemed to go to 404, here's an updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/R8cxH/5/)

Comment: @Chris it isn't white: http://jsfiddle.net/R8cxH/6/ Looks like setting width and height clears the canvas.

Answer (score 4):

Use HTML attributes:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="1000"></canvas>
```

If you need to set those properties dynamically, assign `width` and `height` properties before `getContext()`:

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
c.width = 500;
c.height = 1000;
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: Thanks, but what should I do if I need to set the width and height dynamically in JavaScript?

Comment: You are showing css size in the last example - size needs to be set directly on the element: c.width = 500, c.height = 1000

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware could you explain the difference?

Comment: @Pavlo yes, setting the size using css leaves canvas at 300x150 (default size) no matter what size you set by css so the canvas will get scaled and content probably not fit. Set it directly as properties so the actual canvas size (context) changes (this is what you do in the html tag)

Comment: +1 for the 300*150, I spent long hours till I got that result the hard way. But can't you tell me why width can't accept 100% value?